# How to check is kafka server is Running in PHP / Lumen / Laravel?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need help on kafka. We are connecting to kafka once post created successfully in lumen api. After that sending push to kafka. I'm using below code to sending this.

```
    $conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
    $conf->set('metadata.broker.list', $this->_getHost() . ':' . $this->_getPort());
    $producer = new \RdKafka\Producer($conf);
    // $producer = $this->connect();
    $topic = $producer->newTopic($kafkaTopic);
    $topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, json_encode(['body' => json_encode($kafkaMessage), 'properties' => [],
        'headers' => [],
    ]));
    $result = $producer->flush(10000);
```

However, After creating post when calling the kafka and sometimes it's getting error that kafka server is stop.

So, need methodology / stratagy that how can we check that kafka is running or not before creating post.